# Query with Subquery in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
select complaint_id,
       feedback,
       mobile,
       status,
       reopen,
       parent_complaint_id,
       server_time,
       completion_date, 
       Count(*)
from complaint_details_v2 
where status !=0 
group by feedback,complaint_id,mobile 
order by parent_complaint_id
```

This query fetch the below results

```
Complaint_id    Feedback    Mobile  Status  Reopen  Parent_complaint_id Server_time Completion_date count
194         Xyz         99---   3   0   194 27-08-2017  28-11-2017  1
195         Abc         99--    5   0   196 27-08-2017  28-11-2017  1
214         Dug         99- 5   1   214 27-08-2017  28-11-2017  1
1599        Dug         99- 5   0   214 27-08-2017  28-11-2017  1
```

I want if parent_complaint_id is not repeated then insert single
record of another table otherwise insert record based on the repeated
parent_complaint_id. In the above output table there is two
parent_complaint is repeated that is "214" so in other table i have to
pick complaint id, status, reopen,parent_complaint_id but 7 record
will be inserted in behalf of these parent_complaint_id like below

```
Complaint_id    Status  Reopen  Parent_complaint_id Server_time
194              3        0          194             27-08-2017
195              5        0          196             27-08-2017
214              5        0          214             27-08-2017
214              5        1          214             27-08-2017
214              0        0          214             27-08-2017
214              5        0          214             27-08-2017
214              5        1          214             27-08-2017
214              0        0          214             27-08-2017
214              5        0          214             27-08-2017
```

The above is based on if parent_complaint_id is repeated two times if parent_complaint_id repeated 3 times then insert the value in another table like below:

```
Complaint_id    Status  Reopen  Parent_complaint_id Server_time
194             3        0       194                27-08-2017
195             5        0       196                27-08-2017
214             5        0       214                27-08-2017
214             5        1       214                27-08-2017
214             0        0       214                27-08-2017
214             5        0       214                27-08-2017
214             5        1       214                27-08-2017
214             0        0       214                27-08-2017
214             5        0       214                27-08-2017
214             5        1       214                27-08-2017
214             0        0       214                27-08-2017
214             5        0       214                27-08-2017
```

Comment: Interesting this query even ran successfully since non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` are not included in `GROUP BY` clause which should fail.

Comment: actually the above select query ran successfully the problem is insertion in record in another table with comparison of status

Comment: Forgive me. I still cannot see how that posted query does not error out with [42803 grouping error](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/errcodes-appendix.html) as *status*, *reopen*, *parent_complaint_id*, and still others **should** be in `GROUP BY` clause. See example where I omitted a `SELECT` column from `GROUP BY`: https://rextester.com/AQVWD47343.

Comment: Maybe you are running a non-ANSI SQL mode in Postgres that allows this and until now I only know MySQL to infamously allow *only full group by* mode to be turned off.

Comment: @Parfait: i don't know why you are focusing on select query which is running fine the problem is in insertion, i have to built a insert query on the basis of thisselect subquery

Comment: Can you please set up a rextester example as I have done that runs on its own with a sample of your *complaint_details_v2* data? In all my knowledge of SQL, this `SELECT` query cannot run in Postgres without error. You may have copied it wrong from your end into this post. On StackOverflow we ask posters for a [MCVE].